# When a user has forgotten their password, how to let them set a new one?

Tags: 7, users

A user has forgotten her password, so she uses the 'forgotten password' function. She receives an email with one-time login, and proceeds to edit her profile to set a new password.

But that form requires the old password in order to reset password. A catch 22 situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forgotten password function should not require the old password.  Rather, the password reset link that you get in the email should take you to a password reset page immediately.

The path I got was something like `domain.com/user/37/edit?pass-reset-token=[long token string]` and on this page, it immediately asks for your new password which you must set.

Comment: Thanks. The email template has the correct token (
[user:one-time-login-url]) but the URL it emails doesn't contain the word 'edit'. It looks like this http://domain.com/user/reset/7/xxxxx. Clicking it takes me to a page with a login link, and then I'm logged in. It doesn't take me to a password reset page immediately?

Comment: I just tested this and it took me to the account edit page where no old password was required. Do you have additional modules enabled that might be fiddling with the default behavior? The token used in my password reset email is [user:one-time-login-url]. My reset URL looked like this: http://example.com/user/reset/1/1312385639/g8MQYpmYeq5352WlzjrcrXBLC1cAmg5H2OI85aK1XXc

Comment: Ah I found the problem. The site had a trigger/action set to direct to the homepage on login. Stupidly I didn't check for that. Many thanks to nmc and rfay for the spot on answers.

Comment: If you want to keep the rule though http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/38359/39617

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here. My site had an action set to direct to the homepage on login. This helped me a lot to identify it. My solution was to disable the action an set a destination parameter by GET in my template to redirect user to the homepage on login. "/user?destination=/"