# How can I redirect users upon password reset?

Tags: users, 6, rules

The solution shown in [How can I redirect users upon login sometimes but not break the "Forgot password?" function?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38359/rules-how-can-i-redirect-users-upon-login-sometimes-but-not-break-the-forgot-p) work for Drupal 7.

In Drupal 6, with the *User:user has logged in* event and the following PHP conditions, nothing happens.

```
if (arg(0) == 'user' && arg(1) == 'reset') { 
  return false; 
} else { 
  return true; 
}
```

How can I redirect users upon password reset in Drupal 6?

PS. The only variable for this event is `$account` for the logged-in user.

This is the exported rule I am using.

```
array (
  'rules' => 
  array (
    'rules_passwordreset' => 
    array (
      '#type' => 'rule',
      '#set' => 'event_user_login',
      '#label' => 'passwordreset',
      '#active' => 1,
      '#weight' => '0',
      '#categories' => 
      array (
      ),
      '#status' => 'custom',
      '#conditions' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          '#weight' => 0,
          '#type' => 'condition',
          '#settings' => 
          array (
            'code' => 'if (arg(0) == \'user\' && arg(1) == \'reset\') { 
  return false; 
} else { 
  return true; 
}',
            'vars' => 
            array (
            ),
          ),
          '#name' => 'rules_condition_custom_php',
          '#info' => 
          array (
            'label' => 'Execute custom PHP code',
            'module' => 'PHP',
            'eval input' => 
            array (
              0 => 'code',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      '#actions' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          '#weight' => 0,
          '#info' => 
          array (
            'label' => 'Page redirect',
            'module' => 'System',
            'eval input' => 
            array (
              0 => 'path',
              1 => 'query',
              2 => 'fragment',
            ),
          ),
          '#name' => 'rules_action_drupal_goto',
          '#settings' => 
          array (
            'path' => 'http://www.sample.com',
            'query' => '',
            'fragment' => '',
            'force' => 0,
            'immediate' => 0,
          ),
          '#type' => 'action',
        ),
      ),
      '#version' => 6003,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: will the [LoginToboggan](http://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module not work?

Answer (score 1):

You can define submit function in your password form_alter and then `$form_state['redirect'] = 'user';` or `'user/register'`